# Как правильно: ковришка или коврижка?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишется: *ковришка* или *коврижка*?

Comment: Ковришка (или ковришко) - это уменьшительное от "ковёр", а про чередование Г/Ж  Вам Сибилла рассказала (коврига - коврижка).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: коврижка.

Из словаря: КОВРИГА,  Большой круглый хлеб; каравай. К. хлеба.

КОВРИЖКА, - 1. Уменьш. к Коврига. 2. Пряник, обычно медовый, с прослойкой из повидла или варенья. Медовая к. Испечь коврижку.

Ковриг/а - ковриж/к/а, историческое чередование **Г/Ж** в корне (чередуются **звонкие согласные**), К - уменьшительный суффикс.